# Jquery closest and find doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find, closest

These are my codes. I can't get my jquery code to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
  <input name="hImage" class="form-control"  type="file" id="headerImage" required> 
  <img src="" id="img_url" alt="your image" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
function readURL(e){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        $(reader).load(function(e) {
            imagePrev = e.target.result;
            var imgElement = $(this).closest('div').find('img');
            imgElement.attr('src', imagePrev);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);   
};
```

I trigger the function with this code:

```
$("#headerImage").change(readURL);
```

`imagePrev` is a base64 data. Which works because when I try

```
$("#img_url").attr('src', imagePrev);
```

the image gets loaded.

But I want to use the .closest or .find or .siblings or whatever code is necessary so I can find the nearest img tag and replace its src attr.

Comment: Please build a complete reproducible example. Best is to use the snippet tool available when editing your question. The main missing part is how you call your js code.

Comment: The jquery code, where is it ? The "this" in wich context is ? Add the code that contains it ... is essential to know "this" what it refers to.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `this` variable, once the execution comes inside the `$(reader).load()`, the value changes for `this` variable.

Use the following.

```
function readURL(e){
    $this = $(this);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        $(reader).load(function(e) {
            imagePrev = e.target.result;
            var imgElement = $this.siblings('img');
            imgElement.attr('src', imagePrev);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL($this[0].files[0]);  
    } 
};
```

Comment: Oww nice. It worked. Could you please explain why it worked? Thank You.

Comment: @RJDO The problem is with the `this` variable, once the execution comes inside the `$(reader).load()`, the value changes for `this` variable.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. Thank You very much Sir. :D

Comment: Doing `$this.siblings('img');` would be even better, not going up and down in the DOM  ;)

Comment: @RJDO callbacks inside event listeners always (I'm pretty sure) change the context (this). It is an idiom to see something like `var that = this` just outside such structure to keep a reference of the outter context

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for telling me. I changed my code to .siblings()   :D